# Per tile lighting XNA / MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, lighting

I am making tile based 2D game with MonoGame. I have been trying to implement per tile lighting, and ended up using a recursive flood fill to achieve the effect from this answer https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/68803.

```
private void UpdateLight(int X, int Y, int LightLevel)
{
    //Check if position is out of bounds
    if (X >= 0 && X < MapWidth && Y >= 0 && Y < MapHeight)
        if (LightLevel > BlockMap[X, Y].Light)
        {
            BlockMap[X, Y].Light = LightLevel;

            UpdateLight(X, Y - 1, LightLevel - 1);
            UpdateLight(X, Y + 1, LightLevel - 1);
            UpdateLight(X - 1, Y, LightLevel - 1);
            UpdateLight(X + 1, Y, LightLevel - 1);
        }
}
```

This seemed to work great, until I wanted to remove light sources. I simply cannot figure out a way to do this. When I want to place a light source I would simply call UpdateLight(LightSourceX, LightSourceY, LightSourceStrength). What I essentially need is a method to reverse this recursive flood fill.

To allow for removal of light sources, would I need to use a completely different algorithm all together, or is there some way?

The lighting in practice:

[image]

Comment: _"until I wanted to remove light sources"_ -  Could you not just loop over `BlockMap` setting `Light=0`?  Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

As Micky Duncan suggested, I simply looped over every onscreen tile, set the light to 0, and then recalculated the lightmap. I was too fixated on trying to undo a light, that I didn't even think about resetting it as a whole.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to have helped :)